# Sklearn: Evaluate performance of each classifier of OneVsRestClassifier inside GridSearchCV

Tags: python, scikit-learn, multilabel-classification, grid-search

I am dealing with multi-label classification with `OneVsRestClassifier` and `SVC`,

```
from sklearn.datasets import make_multilabel_classification
from sklearn.multiclass import OneVsRestClassifier
from sklearn.svm import SVC
from sklearn.grid_search import GridSearchCV

L=3
X, y = make_multilabel_classification(n_classes=L, n_labels=2,
                                  allow_unlabeled=True,
                                  random_state=1, return_indicator=True)    
model_to_set = OneVsRestClassifier(SVC())

parameters = {
    "estimator__C": [1,2,4,8],
    "estimator__kernel": ["poly","rbf"],
    "estimator__degree":[1, 2, 3, 4],
}

model_tunning = GridSearchCV(model_to_set, param_grid=parameters,
                             scoring='f1')

model_tunning.fit(X, y)

print model_tunning.best_score_
print model_tunning.best_params_

#0.855175822314
#{'estimator__kernel': 'poly', 'estimator__C': 1, 'estimator__degree': 3}
```

**1st question**

What is the number `0.85` representing for? Is it the best score among the `L` classifiers or the averaged one? Similarly, does the set of parameters stand for the best-scorer among `L` classifiers?

**2nd question**

Based on the fact that, if I am right, the `OneVsRestClassifier` literally builds `L` classifiers for each label, one can expect to access or observe the performance of EACH LABEL. But how, in the above example, to obtain `L` scores from the `GridSearchCV` object?

**EDIT**

To simplify the problem and help myself understand more about `OneVsRestClassifier`, before tuning model,

```
model_to_set.fit(X,y)
gp = model_to_set.predict(X) # the "global" prediction
fp = model_to_set.estimators_[0].predict(X) # the first-class prediction
sp = model_to_set.estimators_[1].predict(X) # the second-class prediction
tp = model_to_set.estimators_[2].predict(X) # the third-class prediction
```

It can be shown that `gp.T[0]==fp`, `gp.T[1]==sp` and `gp.T[2]==tp`. So the "global" prediction is simply the 'sequential' `L` individual predictions and the **2nd question is solved**.

But it is still confusing for me that if one meta-classifier `OneVsRestClassifier` contains `L` classifiers, how can `GridSearchCV` returns only ONE best score, corresponding to one of 4*2*4 sets of parameters, for a meta-classifier `OneVsRestClassifier` having `L` classifiers?

It would be fairly appreciated to see any comment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`GridSearchCV` creates grid from your parameter values, it evaluates your `OneVsRestClassifier` as atomic classifier (I.e. `GridSearchCV` doesn't know what is inside this metaclassifier)

**First**: 0.85 is the best score of `OneVsRestClassifier` among all possible combinations (16 combinations in your case, 4*2*4) of parameters `("estimator__C", "estimator__kernel", "estimator__degree")`, it means  that `GridSearchCV` evaluates 16 (again, it's only in this particular case) possible `OneVsRestClassifier`'s each of which contains L `SVC`'s. All of that L classifiers inside one `OneVsRestClassifier` have same values of parameters (but each of them is learning to recognize their own class from L possible)

i.e. from set of

```
{OneVsRestClassifier(SVC(C=1, kernel="poly", degree=1)),
 OneVsRestClassifier(SVC(C=1, kernel="poly", degree=2)),
 ...,
 OneVsRestClassifier(SVC(C=8, kernel="rbf", degree=3)),
 OneVsRestClassifier(SVC(C=8, kernel="rbf", degree=4))}
```

it chooses one with the best score.

`model_tunning.best_params_` here represents parameters for OneVsRestClassifier(SVC()) with which it will achieve `model_tunning.best_score_`.
You can get that best `OneVsRestClassifier` from `model_tunning.best_estimator_` attribute.

**Second:** There is no ready to use code to obtain separate scores for L classifiers from `OneVsRestClassifier`, but you can look at implementation of `OneVsRestClassifier.fit` method, or take this (should work :) ):

```
# Here X, y - your dataset
one_vs_rest = model_tunning.best_estimator_
yT = one_vs_rest.label_binarizer_.transform(y).toarray().T
# Iterate through all L classifiers
for classifier, is_ith_class in zip(one_vs_rest.estimators_, yT):
    print(classifier.score(X, is_ith_class))
```

Comment: Thanks! In the first one, there are 4*2*4 `OneVsRestClassifier`s in the set and each of which corresponds to `L` classifiers using the same set of parameters. So I am wondering why there is only ONE score for a set parameters rather than `L` scores. Is 0.85 the best score among 4*2*4*`L` models?

Comment: @Francis, No, 0.85 is the best score among 4*2*4 OneVsRestClassifier's (Because you have 4*2*4 combinations of parameters for this classifier). GridSearchCV simply evaluates OneVsRestClassifier on each possible combination and chooses one with best accuracy. You can get all possible combinations of parameters and corresponding scores from grid_scores_ attribute of GridSearchCV, but if you want separated scores for L classifiers from each OneVsRestClassifier (So it's 4*2*4*L scores) - you should write your own code. Sorry for my english maybe something is not clear from what i tried to explain.

Comment: No, it is actually my English is not good as I am not a native speaker :). I think I figured out the behavior of GridSearchCV on the meta-classifier, please help me clarify the answer,  thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Inspired by @Olologin 's answer, I realized that 0.85 is the best weighted average of f1 scores (in this example) obtained by `L` predictions. In the following code, I evaluate the model by inner test, using macro average of f1 score:

```
# Case A, inspect F1 score using the meta-classifier
F_A = f1_score(y, model_tunning.best_estimator_.predict(X), average='macro')

# Case B, inspect F1 scores of each label (binary task) and collect them by macro average
F_B = []
for label, clc in zip(y.T, model_tunning.best_estimator_.estimators_):
    F_B.append(f1_score(label, clf.predict(X)))
F_B = mean(F_B)

F_A==F_B # True
```

So it implies that the `GridSearchCV` applies one of 4*2*4 sets of parameters to build the meta-classifier which in turn makes prediction on each label with one of the `L` classifiers. The outcome will be `L` f1 scores for `L` labels, each of which is a performance of a binary task. Finally, a single score is obtained by taking average (macro or weighted average, specified by parameter in f1_score) of `L` f1 scores.

The `GridSearchCV` then choose the best averaged f1 scores among 4*2*4 sets of parameters, which is 0.85 in this example.

Though it is convenient to use the wrapper for multi-label problem, it can only maximize the averaged f1 score with a same set of parameters used to build `L` classifiers. If one wants to optimize the performance of each label separately, one seems to have to build `L` classifiers without using the wrapper.

Comment: > If one wants to optimize the performance of each label separately, one seems to have to build L classifiers without using the wrapper.
Yes, you understood it right.

Comment: Thank you! So it seems to me that one should use the wrapper if the optimization for each class is not the main concern. Because besides that and the convenience, there is no other difference between using the wrapper and building `L` models by hand.

Answer (score 3):

As for your second question, you might want to used `GridSearchCV` with [scikit-multilearn](http://scikit.ml/)'s [BinaryRelevance](http://scikit.ml/api/api/skmultilearn.problem_transform.html#module-skmultilearn.problem_transform.br) classifier. Like `OneVsRestClassifier`, Binary Relevance creates L single-label classifiers, one per label. For each label the training data is 1 if label is present and 0 if not present. The best selected classifier set is the `BinaryRelevance` class instance in `best_estimator_` property of `GridSearchCV`. Use for predicting floats of probabilities use the `predict_proba` method of the `BinaryRelevance` object. An example can be found in the [scikit-multilearn docs for model selection](http://scikit.ml/api/model_estimation.html).

In your case I would run the following code:

```
from skmultilearn.problem_transform import BinaryRelevance
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
import sklearn.metrics

model_to_set = BinaryRelevance(SVC())

parameters = {
    "classifier__estimator__C": [1,2,4,8],
    "classifier__estimator__kernel": ["poly","rbf"],
    "classifier__estimator__degree":[1, 2, 3, 4],
}

model_tunning = GridSearchCV(model_to_set, param_grid=parameters,
                             scoring='f1')

model_tunning.fit(X, y)

# for some X_test testing set
predictions = model_tunning.best_estimator_.predict(X_test)

# average=None gives per label score
metrics.f1_score(y_test, predictions, average = None)
```

Please note that there much better methods for multi-label classification than Binary Relevance :) You can find them in [madjarov's comparison](http://kt.ijs.si/DragiKocev/wikipage/lib/exe/fetch.php?media=2012pr_ml_comparison.pdf) or [my recent paper](http://www.mdpi.com/1099-4300/18/8/282).